# UIActivityViewController Custom Title

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

[image: Custom Title]

I want to change icons title and Cancel button text to my language can some one help me please 
This is sample code

```
UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SampleImg.png"];
NSArray *Items   = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         @"A text line", 
                         anImage, nil];

UIActivityViewController *ActivityView = 
        [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
               initWithActivityItems:Items applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:ActivityView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: this is not possible without hackery that is likely to get your app rejected from the store

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the `Cancel` button text directly, but it will be automatically localised. In order to change the titles of the icons you will have to create subclasses of `UIActivity` and override `activityTitle`:

```
- (NSString *)activityTitle
{
    // title of your app
    return @"Do stuff";
}
```

Keep in mind that the string returned in `activityTitle` [should be localised](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011974-CH1-SW5).